# wordpress categories: how to find the last child category for a post

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a category structure that is 5 levels deep. when returning the categories for a post, these categories are not in any particular order. I need to find the last child category for a post.

Comment: This is an ideal question for the new http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$last_category = $categories[0];

foreach($categories as $i => $category)
{
    if($category->parent == $last_category->cat_ID)
    {
        $last_category = $category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [wp_get_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `$post_ID`, just call `wp_get_object_terms($post_ID)`. It returns an array with every category for that post, referencing parents and children.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using them in the loop, you could try this:

```
<?php the_category("", "single"); ?>
```

Ref: [the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

===== UPDATED =====

Outside the loop:

```
<?php the_category("", "single", $post->ID); ?>
```

Comment: I need to get the child category outside the loop using the post ID.

Comment: Added back the 3rd param :D. The 3rd param is the post's ID, I shouldn't assumed you are in the loop.